# grub2 terminal: redirect command output to file

Tags: grub2, ubuntu-20.04

I refer to the syntax used by grub2, for example when you start a pendrive and you are presented with the grub2 terminal.
I would like to redirect the output of the [lsmod](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#lsmod) command to a file in some persistent filesystem (e.g. to view later outside GRUB).
The word `command > file` does not work unlike the linux shell.
What is the equivalent for grub2?
There is nothing on the internet to give me the answer, otherwise I would not have posted the question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of `grub-mount`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Invoking-grub_002dmount) states [emphasis mine]:

> Since **GRUB intentionally contains no code for writing to file systems**, it can easily provide a guaranteed read-only mount mechanism.

The conclusion is it's not possible to save anything to a persistent file from within GRUB.